# Unable to parse data from PHP to Python

Tags: php, python, xml

I am trying to pass data from my PHP script to my Python script in order to write the data from Python to an XML file.

PHP Script:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

#--Fetching data from the Form
$fserverId = $_POST['field1'];
$finsname = $_POST['field2'];
$fhost = $_POST['field3'];
$fport = $_POST['field4'];
$fproto = $_POST['field5'];
$fuserName = $_POST['field6'];
$fpassword = $_POST['field7'];
$fkey = $_POST['field8'];
$fcompanyName = $_POST['field9'];
$fofficeAddress = $_POST['field10'];
$fstate = $_POST['field11'];
$fcountry = $_POST['field12'];
$fladmin = $_POST['field13'];
$fphone = $_POST['field14'];
$fmobile = $_POST['field15'];
$femail = $_POST['field16'];
$fdesignation = $_POST['field17'];
$frManager = $_POST['field18'];

$data = " --serverId ".$fserverId." --name ".$finsname." --host ".$fhost." --port ".$fport." --proto ".$fproto." --username ".$fuserName." --password ".$fpassword." --key ".$fkey." --companyName ".$fcompanyName." --officeAddress ".$fofficeAddress." --state ".$fstate." --country ".$fcountry." --ladmin ".$fladmin." --phone ".$fphone." --mobile ".$fmobile." --email ".$femail." --designation ".$fdesignation." --rManager ".$frManager;

#--Parsing the data from PHPscript to CGI
echo "Firewall Creation:: ".$data;
$output = exec('python3 /var/www/cgi-bin/dscr.cgi' .$data);
echo "<pre>hello -------</pre>";
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

}
?>
```

Python Script:

```
import cgi, cgitb
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import os
from xml.dom import minidom
import sys
import argparse
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()

#--ADDING THE XML FILE HERE
base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
xml_file = os.path.join(base_path, "company.xml")

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

print (xml_file)

#--PARSING THE ARGUMENTS
#--To be used to get arguments from Command Line or Php Script
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description ='parser script')
parser.add_argument('--serverId', required=True, help='Server ID to find device info')
parser.add_argument('--name', required=True, help='Name Of the Policy')
parser.add_argument('--host', default='any', help='Host of the IP Address')
parser.add_argument('--port', default='any', help='Port used')
parser.add_argument('--proto', default='any', help='Protocol used')
parser.add_argument('--username', default='any', help='Username')
parser.add_argument('--password', default='any', help='Password')
parser.add_argument('--key', default='any', help='')
parser.add_argument('--companyName', default='any', help='Name of the Company')
parser.add_argument('--officeAddress', default='any', help='Address of the Company')
parser.add_argument('--state', default='any', help='State')
parser.add_argument('--country', default='any', help='Country')
parser.add_argument('--ladmin', default='any', help='Local Admin')
parser.add_argument('--phone', default='any', help='Phone Number')
parser.add_argument('--mobile', default='any', help='Mobile Number')
parser.add_argument('--email', default='any', help='Email Address')
parser.add_argument('--designation', default='any', help='Designation of the concerned')
parser.add_argument('--rManager', default='any', help='Reporting Manager of the concerned Person')
args = parser.parse_args()


#--Associating variables to parsed arguments
name = args.name
host = args.host
port = args.port
proto = args.proto
user = args.username
password = args.password
key = args.key
company = args.companyName
officeAddr = args.officeAddress
state = args.state
country = args.country
ladmin = args.ladmin
phone = args.phone
mobile = args.mobile
email = args.email
designation = args.designation
reportingMgr = args.rManager

#--Retrieving the element tree from XML file
tree = et.parse(xml_file)

root = tree.getroot()

#--Creating Elements and input value
new_name = et.Element("name")
new_name.text = name
new_host = et.Element("host")
new_host.text = host
new_port = et.Element("port")
new_port.text = port
new_proto = et.Element("proto")
new_proto.text = proto
new_user = et.Element("user")
new_user.text = user
new_password = et.Element("password")
new_password.text = password
new_key = et.Element("key")
new_key.text = key
new_companyName = et.Element("companyName")
new_companyName.text = company

new_address = et.Element("address")
new_officeAddr = et.Element("officeAddr")
new_officeAddr.text = officeAddr
new_state = et.Element("state")
new_state.text = state
new_country = et.Element("country")
new_country.text = country

new_contact = et.Element("contact")
new_ladmin = et.Element("ladmin")
new_ladmin.text = ladmin
new_phone = et.Element("phone")
new_phone.text = phone
new_mobile = et.Element("mobile")
new_mobile.text = mobile
new_email = et.Element("email")
new_email.text = email
new_designation = et.Element("designation")
new_designation.text = designation
new_reportingMgr = et.Element("reportingManager")
new_reportingMgr.text = reportingMgr

new_address.append(new_officeAddr)
new_address.append(new_state)
new_address.append(new_country)

new_contact.append(new_ladmin)
new_contact.append(new_phone)
new_contact.append(new_mobile)
new_contact.append(new_email)
new_contact.append(new_designation)
new_contact.append(new_reportingMgr)

new_server = et.Element("server")
new_server.append(new_name)
new_server.append(new_host)
new_server.append(new_port)
new_server.append(new_proto)
new_server.append(new_user)
new_server.append(new_password)
new_server.append(new_key)
new_server.append(new_companyName)
new_server.append(new_address)
new_server.append(new_contact)
root.append(new_server)

str = et.tostring(root)
reparsed = minidom.parseString(str)
tree.write(xml_file)
with open(xml_file, 'w') as output:
 output.write(reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="\t"))
```

On trying to execute, the data does not get written on the XML file but when I pass the arguments through Command Line in the python script, it does get written. So there must be a problem in the call/bridge between the two scripts due to which the data I'm trying to send from PHP to Python is not getting parsed.

Comment: Also, when printing the XML File, the indentation of the last set of data that was written stays fine but the one above it gets distorted everytime some new data is added

Comment: Is the command built without problem? Did you miss any quotes?

Comment: Yes @Raptor the command is built without any problem as such and no quotes are missing since it is getting executed everytime I call the scripts individually but when i try to call the python script using my PHP script, the write is never successful

Comment: Imaging the command line when `field1` is `; rm -rf /;`.

Comment: @KlausD. how does that help? I mean, `; rm -rf/;` is usually used to force the recursive removal of some Directory

Comment: It shows how dangerous your approach is. Anybody using this could run any command on your system.

Comment: Thanks for that @KlausD. but that still does not solve the persisting problem. I will edit my code as suggested by you but this will only secure my system. Also, can you please elaborate on how the approach of mine is dangerous as I am a newbie in coding using Python